# Parsing command line using argv and argc in C

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, command-prompt, argv

I'm trying to figure out how to get commands from the command line and when getting that command perform a certain method. I can't get the code to recognize the inputted values. Any ideas?

getopts, fgets, or anything of the sort hasn't worked either.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
int i = 1;

while((argc > 1) && (argv[i] != "d")) {
   switch (argv[i]) {
     case: "a":
       callMethodA(atoi(argv[i+1]));
       break;
     case: "b":
       callMethodB(atoi(argv[i+1]));
       break;
     case: "c":
       callMethodC(atoi(argv[i+1]));
       break;
     default:
       printf("command not recognized");
   }
   argc++
   i+=2;
}
```

what's suppose to happen is say inputted as:

```
a 3 5 1 b 2 1 c      4
```

it would call the function callMethodA() with the parameter int of 3 so

```
callMethodA(3);
callMethodA(5);
callMethodA(1);
callMethodB(2);
callMethodB(1);
callMethodC(4);
```

EDIT  from suggestion by PureW

```
int i = 1;

while((argc > 1) && (strcmp(argv[i], "d") != 0)) {
    if(strcmp(argv[i], "a")) callMethodA(atoi(argv[i+1]));
    else if(strcmp(argv[i], "b")) callMethodB(atoi(argv[i+1]));
    else if(strcmp(argv[i], "c")) callMethodC(atoi(argv[i+1]));

    argc++;
    i+=2;
}
```

no limit is placed on the order of the commands or on the number of values cal

Comment: why you have put "a" in front of each case.

Comment: You cannot use a switch/case to do string comparisons (but even if you could, the syntax you're using wouldn't do it). If you include in your question, an example of a command line you'd like to use, I'm sure you'll get a better response.

Comment: While you cannot use string comparisons in `switch` you can use chars...

Comment: You tried `fgets` to get command line arguments? I'd be interested in that try.

Comment: @mah added an example

Comment: @MantoshKumar That has been fixed, thank you for pointing it out. Code has been edited.

Comment: @urzeit Thank you for pointing that out, it was a silly error. It has been fixed and edited code has been added

Comment: @user3493898 your command line example doesn't match up with your code. In code, you're saying that each of arguments a, b, and c (which live in `argv[i]` make use of a single additional argument (`argv[i+1]`), and after processing, parsing picks up at `i+=2`. However, your example suggests `a` relies on `argv[i+1]`, `argv[i+2]`, and `argv[i+3]`, where `b` relies on two additional arguments, and only `c` uses just one. Either your command line will have to look like `a 3 a 5 a 1 b 2 b 1 c 4` or you're going to have to change your logic to keep calling `callMethodX()` until appropriate to stop.

Answer (score 2):

`argv` is a vector of char pointers. So each `argv[i]` is actually a memory address. Doing a regular comparison as `argv[1] == "a"` will not work since you are comparing memory locations.

What you want to do is use `strcmp(argv[1], "a")`. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/

Comment: Wouldn't it be argv[i]?

Comment: Edited question with your suggestion... is the code what you meant?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You have to use if-else instead of switch-statements for string comparison as far as I know.